# Spark EMR S3 Processing Large No of Files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I have around 15000 files (ORC) present in S3 where each file contain few minutes worth of data and size of each file varies between 300-700MB.

Since recursively looping through a directory present in YYYY/MM/DD/HH24/MIN format is expensive, I am creating a file which contain list of all S3 files for a given day (objects_list.txt) and passing this file as input to spark read API

```
val file_list = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/objects_list.txt"))
val paths: mutable.Set[String] = mutable.Set[String]()
    for (line <- file_list.getLines()) {
      if(line.length > 0 && line.contains("part"))
        paths.add(line.trim)
    }

val eventsDF = spark.read.format("orc").option("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown","true").load(paths.toSeq: _*)
eventsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
```

The Size of the cluster is 10 r3.4xlarge machines (workers)(Where Each Node: 120GB RAM and 16 cores) and master is of m3.2xlarge config (

The problem which am facing is, spark read was running endlessly and I see only driver working and rest all Nodes aren't doing anything and am not sure why driver is opening each S3 file for reading, because AFAIK spark works lazily so till an action is called reading shouldn't happen, I think it's listing each file and collecting some metadata associated with it.

But why only Driver is working and rest all Nodes aren't doing anything and how can I make this operation to run in parallel on all worker nodes ?

I have come across these articles https://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219 and https://gist.github.com/snowindy/d438cb5256f9331f5eec, but here the entire file contents are being read as an RDD, but my use case is depending on the columns being referred only those blocks/columns of data should be fetched from S3 (columnar access given ORC is my storage) . Files in S3 have around 130 columns but only 20 fields are being referred and processed using dataframe API's

```
Sample Log Messages:
17/10/08 18:31:15 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://xxxx/flattenedDataOrc/data=eventsTable/y=2017/m=09/d=20/h=09/min=00/part-r-00199-e4ba7eee-fb98-4d4f-aecc-3f5685ff64a8.zlib.orc' for reading
17/10/08 18:31:15 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://xxxx/flattenedDataOrc/data=eventsTable/y=2017/m=09/d=20/h=19/min=00/part-r-00023-5e53e661-82ec-4ff1-8f4c-8e9419b2aadc.zlib.orc' for reading
```

You can see below that only One Executor is running that to driver program on one of the task Nodes(Cluster Mode) and CPU is 0% on rest of the other Nodes(i.e Workers) and even after 3-4 hours of processing, the situation is same given huge number of files have to be processed
[image: Only One Executor is Active i.e Driver]

Any Pointers on how can I avoid this issue, i.e speed up the load and process  ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution that can help you based in AWS Glue.

You have a lot of files partitioned in your S3. But you have partitions based in timestamp. So using glue you can use your objects in S3 like "hive tables" in your EMR.

First you need to create a EMR with version 5.8+ and you will be able to see this:

[image]

You can set up this checking both options. This will allow to access the AWS Glue Data Catalog.

After this you need to add the your root folder to the AWS Glue Catalog. The fast way to do that is using the Glue Crawler. This tool will crawl your data and will create the catalog as you need.

I will suggest you to take a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html).

After the crawler runs, this will have the metadata of your table in the catalog that you can see at [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/).

In Athena you can check if your data was properly identified by the crawler.

This solution will make your spark works close to a real HDFS. Due to the metadata will be properly in the Data Catalog. And the time you app is taking to find the "indexing" will allow to run the jobs faster.

Working with this here I was able to improve the queries, and working with partitions was much better with glue. So, have a try this probably can help in the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But is there any other generic solution apart from AWS Glue, what if some one is running their App on GCE or Azure ? , I think it's a very common problem and people might be doing something to get rid of this bottleneck, interested in knowing about that solution

Comment: On a different note, is there any reference on how to refer/connect to Glue catalog table from EMR, their documentation didn't have any samples/examples

Comment: About this is not much. If you create an EMR cluster checking those two things above. You can point to the table as you point to a Hive table using spark. Just using like this: `val myDf = spark.table("database.table")` and you have your dataframe.

Comment: Just now checked and Glue is not yet available in Singapore where my input data is located, any other Approach ? Will try creating Hive metadata, but is there any other approach ?

Comment: That is hard to say :( you can try to create an external table via Hive pointing to your S3 bucket. This can help you as well. https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-hive/index.html